# Program to change language of audio stream in video file

Tags: gratis, video, windows-8

I've downloaded a few movies in mp4 and mkv format.
When I look at the properties of some of them, I see that the language of the audio stream is set to "Undefined", and not "English", while the movie itself is in English.

I tried to change this using File Properties in Windows 8.1, but the only things I can change there are "Director", "Producer", etc, and not the audio streams.

<sup>*(just to clarify, I want to change the audio stream properties, not the audio itself)*</sup>
Is there a program that can do this?

- I'd prefer if it has a GUI, but CLI should also be fine (as long as it isn't too complicated).
- It should save the changes directly to the original file, no converting required.
- And, of course, it has to be gratis (open-source not required, but preferred).

Comment: Did you ever find a piece of software that can do this? I can do this with subbler but need a windows alternative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Avidemux**](http://avidemux.org/) can do that too.

- GUI
- free / open-source
- cross-platform
- it doesn't re-encode video as long as you keep the same codecs

Open you video file, go to <kbd>Audio</kbd> menu and choose <kbd>Select Track</kbd>. You'll see this:

[image: Audio Tracks Configuration: Track 1: Enabled: English]

Change the language to whatever you want then save the file using <kbd>Copy</kbd> for both audio and video codecs.

**This applies only to the Windows version of Avidemux.**

Although Avidemux is a cross-platform application, on Linux the <kbd>Audio</kbd> menu looks different. It can only handle two audio streams and cannot modify the language.

[image]

Comment: It works, although it does create a copy of the original file (that luckily is roughly the same size as the original), which isn't completely what I want... Well, at least I can easily delete the original. I'll set this as the accepted answer for now.

Answer (score 4):

[**Libav**](http://libav.org/) can be used:

- freeware / open-source
- command-line
- cross-platform
- creates a copy of the original file

To set the language of the first audio stream:

```
avconv -i input.mp4 -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -codec copy output.mp4
```

If you have multiple audio streams and you don't know which one you want to change:

```
avprobe input.mp4
```

will show format and type of each media stream in the video file.

Comment: FYI: libav is a fork of the much more popular ffmpeg; I'd recommend using ffmpeg instead (the command is exactly the same; just replace "avconv" with "ffmpeg"). I couldn't even find a pre-built version of libav for my platform (Fedora).

Answer (score 1):

[**VLC media player**](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)'s Media Info dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>) will show a *Save Metadata* button if you type in any of the fields.

[image: VLC media info with 'save metadata' button showing]

Takes a long time so it too must work by making an intermediate copy.

Another possibility is one of the many [MP3/4 Tag Editors](http://alternativeto.net/tag/mp4-tagging/)